# TinyMCE отображаемое в редакторе, но не идущее в отправку на сервер

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Делаю виджет для статей на сайте - для выборочного показа статей схожей тематики. Идея заключается в размещении в тексте статьи какого-то фрагмента, который при выводе будет парситься и заменяться на объект из базы.
Примерно так делаю: `<div class="recommend_widget" data-id="188"></div>`, это работает замечательно, и даже в tinyMce написан плагин для поиска подходящих статей, и они прекрасно садятся в текст статьи.

Задача - динамически отображать название рекомендованной статьи **в редакторе tinyMce**. То есть так же грузить из базы и показывать. Да так, чтобы html отображения не отправлялся при сохранении.
Полагаю, в tinyMce есть какие-то готовые инструменты для этого.

Прошу помочь советом. Спасибо!